# Geoserver layers displaced when cache activated

Tags: caching, openlayers, geoserver, map-projections

I am trying to solve a problem for some days, and it is impossible for me even to find the reason of that behaviour of geoserver.
I have a web application that prints some map layers from my geoserver (version 2.1.3) through openlayers.
I have all the layers well configured in my geoserver application and these layers are well drawn by openlayers using the projection 900913.

The problem comes when I try to change from obtaining directly the layer images from my geoserver, to obtain the layers through the geowebcache included in the geoserver distribution (adding in the request the parameter "&tiled=true").

Then the layers are also obtained but some kilometres displaced from the original position.

Maybe it uses a different projection, but in the geoserver logs I saw it is calling the request with the 900913 projection.
I have also wiped the temp directory of the geowebcache where one can find the cache files, to force geowebcache to redraw the layer cache files. But it redraws them with the same problem.

Does somebody have had this problem or know what is the reason of this layer displacement when using the cache layers?

Thank you very much,
Aleix

EDIT: I see there is the same question in that following post in the GIS site of the StackExchange community, although it is neither answered... (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4289/geowebcache-misalignment-of-tiles)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to really use GWC please hit the GWC own WMS service, it will also tell you if the requests you are making are displaced compared to the cached grid:

`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?...`

Comment: Thank very much you Andrea, I had tried with the wms service already but it did not helped me so much..
I can call the 2 following request (with the same identical parameters: layer, srs, bounding box, ) and I obtain 2 different layer parts:

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?request=GetMap&LAYERS=layergroup1...
 And: 
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetMap&LAYERS=layergroup1...